# Is there an after request method in aiohttp like in flask

Tags: python, aiohttp

Flask provides this nice `@app.after_request` decorator which allows to execute a method after an http request has been handled. See documentation [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.after_request).

How would you achieve a similar pattern with **aiohttp**?
Typically to send logs after the request has been handled.

Comment: That's not really the best documentation link for `after_request`. Try http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/reqcontext/?highlight=after_request#callbacks-and-errors and http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.after_request instead.

Comment: The link you gave is for a specific recipe for setting up one-off `after_request` calls for a specific request *only*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters done, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `aiohttp` web server supports [*signals*](https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web_advanced.html#aiohttp-web-signals), which are hooks to be called at specific points.

The [`Application.on_response_prepare` signal](https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web_reference.html#aiohttp.web.Application.on_response_prepare) is the moral equivalent of Flask's `after_request` handler. Use it to modify the response as it is being prepared to be returned to the client:

```
async def on_prepare(request, response):
    response.headers['My-Header'] = 'value'

app.on_response_prepare.append(on_prepare)
```

The signal receives both the `request` and `response` objects. If you want to implement the [Flask pattern for registering a callback *per request*](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/53/), and are using Python 3.7, you can use a [`contextvars` context variable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextvars.html):

```
from contextvars import ContextVar
from typing import Iterable, Callable

from aiohttp import web


PrepareCallback = Callable[[web.Request, web.StreamResponse], None]
call_on_prepare: ContextVar[Iterable[PrepareCallback]] = ContextVar('call_on_prepare', ())


async def per_request_callbacks(request, response):
    # executed sequentially, in order of registration!
    for callback in call_on_prepare.get():
        await callback(request, response)


app.on_response_prepare.append(per_request_callbacks)


def response_prepare_after_this_request(awaitable):
    call_on_prepare.set(call_on_prepare.get() + (awaitable,))
    return awaitable
```

then use it like this in a request:

```
def invalidate_username_cache():
    @response_prepare_after_this_request
    async def delete_username_cookie(request, response):
        response.del_cookie('username')
        return response
```

If you need to support Python versions < 3.7, you'd have to store the list of callbacks on the `app`, `request` or `response` objects instead; see the [data sharing section](https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web_advanced.html#data-sharing-aka-no-singletons-please) of the `aiohttp` FAQ.  Personally, I think that contextvars are the better pattern here, as this provides better encapsulation for utilities like `response_prepare_after_this_request`, which now can be distributed separately without fear of clashing with other data set in the `aiohttp.web` object mappings.